# How to refactor code to avoid error?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I use google appengine and uploading form fields with images. it has been working for years. Now recently we started getting an error message. I get this error message in my appengine logs

```
/upload_form 404 2806ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36 module=default version=brazil
0.1.0.30 - - [11/Apr/2015:15:25:53 -0700] "POST /upload_form HTTP/1.1" 404 84 "http://www.koolbusiness.com/ai" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36" "www.koolbusiness.com" ms=2807 cpu_ms=1970 cpm_usd=0.000009 app_engine_release=1.9.19 instance=00c61b117c883da8804d90f0539b4890fd6a4f
I 2015-04-12 00:25:50.828
user_dict | None 
E 2015-04-12 00:25:53.556
Python int too large to convert to C long
```

It is this code

```
class AdLister(BaseRequestHandler,
               blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    csrf_protect = False

    def post(self):
        message = ''

        ad = Ad()

        if users.get_current_user():
            ad.user = users.get_current_user()

        if self.current_user is not None:
            #logging.debug('usr %s' % str(self.current_user()))
            try:
                ad.usr = self.current_user
            except Exception, e:
                logging.info('exception %s' % str(e))

        if self.request.get('type'):
            ad.type = self.request.get('type')
        if self.request.get('address'):
            ad.address = self.request.get('address')
        if self.request.get('rooms'):
            ad.number_of_rooms = int(self.request.get('rooms'))
        if self.request.get('size'):
            ad.size = float(self.request.get('size'))
        if self.request.get('regdate'):
            ad.regdate = int(self.request.get('regdate'))
        if self.request.get('mileage'):
            ad.mileage = int(self.request.get('mileage'))

        ad.category = self.request.get('category_group')

        form = AdForm(self.request.params)
        #form = AdForm(unicode(self.request.params, "utf8"))
        for city in montaomodel.City.all().fetch(9999999):  # TODO: only do this for the region

            form.area.choices.insert(city.key().id(),
                                     (str(city.key().id()), 'Select...'))

        if form.validate():
            title = to_unicode_or_bust(form.title.data)
            #unicode(form.title.data, 'utf-8')
            ad.title = title
            self.session['title'] = ad.title
            name = to_unicode_or_bust(form.name.data)  #, 'utf-8')
            ad.name = name
            self.session['name'] = ad.name
            ad.email = form.email.data
            self.session['email'] = ad.email
            ad.phoneview = form.phoneview.data
            self.session['phoneview'] = ad.phoneview
            try:
                if form.phonenumber.data:
                    ad.phonenumber = form.phonenumber.data
                    self.session['phonenumber'] = ad.phonenumber
            except:
                pass

            text = to_unicode_or_bust(form.text.data)  # , 'utf8')
            titletest = to_unicode_or_bust(form.title.data)




            ad.text = text
            self.session['text'] = ad.text
            ad.price = form.price.data.replace(' ', '').replace(',00',
                                                                '').replace('.00', '')
            try:
                if form.price.data:
                    ad.integer_price = form.price.data.replace(' ', ''
                    ).replace(',00', '').replace('.00', '')
            except:
                pass
            self.session['price'] = ad.price
            ad.url = self.request.host
            self.session['url'] = self.request.host
            ad.place = self.request.get('place')
            self.session['place'] = ad.place
            ad.postaladress = self.request.get('place')
            self.session['postaladress'] = ad.postaladress
            ad.put()
            self.session['ad_id'] = ad.key().id()
        else:

            self.render('createnewad.html', {
                'user': self.current_user,
                'session': self.auth.get_user_by_session(),
                'request': self.request,
                'form': form,
                'name': to_unicode_or_bust(form.name.data)  #.encode('utf-8')
            })
            return
        if self.request.get('currency'):
            ad.currency = self.request.get('currency')
            self.session['currency'] = ad.currency
        if self.request.get('cg'):
            ad.category = self.request.get('cg')
            self.session['category'] = ad.category
        if self.request.get('company_ad') == '1':
            ad.company_ad = True
            self.session['company_ad'] = 'True'
        ad.put()

        ad.url = self.request.host

        for upload in self.get_uploads():
            try:
                img = Image(reference=ad)
                img.primary_image = upload.key()
                image_url = images.get_serving_url(str(upload.key()), size=640)
                img.put()
                ad.hasimages = True
                ad.image_url = images.get_serving_url(str(upload.key()), size=640)
                ad.put()
                ad.blobs.append(upload.key())
                ad.put()
            except Exception, e:
                logging.error('There was an exception:%s' % str(e))
                pass
        ad.published = False
        if self.request.get('area'):
            city = \
                montaomodel.City.get_by_id(long(self.request.get('area'
                )))
            region = montaomodel.Region.get(city.region.key())
            ad.cities.append(city.key())
            ad.regions.append(region.key())
            ad.city = unicode(city.name)
            ad.region = unicode(region.name)
            ad.put()

        param = {'address': ad.city.encode('utf-8'), 'sensor': 'false'}
        encoded_param = urllib.urlencode(param)
        url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
        url = url + '?' + encoded_param
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        jsondata = json.loads(result.content)

        try:
            latlng = jsondata['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
            lat = latlng['lat']
            lon = latlng['lng']
            ad.geopt = db.GeoPt(lat, lon)
        except Exception, e:
            pass
        ad.put()
        if self.current_user:
            ad.userID = str(self.current_user.auth_ids[0])
            ad.put()
            ad.usr = self.current_user.key.to_old_key()
            ad.put()

        image = ad.matched_images.get()
        image_url = None
        if image:
            if image.primary_image:
                try:
                    image_url = \
                        images.get_serving_url(str(image.primary_image.key()),
                                               size=640)
                except Exception, e:
                    image_url = '/images/' + str(image.key().id()) \
                                + '_small.jpg'
            else:
                image_url = '/images/' + str(image.key().id()) \
                            + '_small.jpg'
        imv = []
        for i in ad.matched_images:
            if i.primary_image:
                try:
                    i1 = \
                        images.get_serving_url(str(i.primary_image.key()))
                    imv.append(i1)
                except Exception, e:
                    i1 = '/images/' + str(image.key().id()) \
                         + '_small.jpg'
                    imv.append(i1)

        if ad.price:  # and doesn't contain separators
            try:
                price = \
                    i18n.I18n(self.request).format_decimal(int(ad.price))
            except Exception, e:
                price = ad.price
        else:
            price = ad.price

        self.render('preview.html', {
            'user': self.current_user,
            'session': self.auth.get_user_by_session(),
            'request': self.request,
            'ad': ad,
            'image_url': image_url,
            'imv': imv,
            'len': len(imv),
            'form': PreviewAdForm(),
            'price': price,
            })
```

### Update

The offending code is this line

`form.area.choices.insert(long(city.key().id()),
                                     (str(city.key().id()), 'Select...'))`

It's IDs that have become too large numbers. I put the statement in a try... block for now so it passes for an error for the time being. I'd like to do a recfactoring so it doesn't fetch all the cities but only the cities for the region.

Comment: Do you have an example of form inputs that will trigger this?

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to help you unless you provide the specific line causing the error. I'm assuming you have your code surround by a try/except and are just printing the error; you also need to print the backtrace (or just re-raise the error and App Engine will automatically log the backtrace).

Comment: @DaveW.Smith The error occurs for any form input that passes validation. It doesn't print the offending line so we can't know what the code is that is vausing the error. We know the function though and that the status says 404 and not 500 which is strange.

Comment: @RSamuelKlatchko I found the specific line by carefully using debug statements. I updated the question with this information.

Comment: There is a lot going on in that line.  I suggest you break it up into a series of statements so you can work which bit is the problem. Also python can normally handle very long int's so it's not clear why python can't deal with a long integer.  The error is odd "Python int too large to convert to C long"  python doesn't normally need to convert to C Long.

Comment: @TimHoffman - that error comes from [PyLong_AsLong](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/long.html) which is part of the API for native extensions. App Engine has some native extensions built in and his code must be using one of them.

Comment: What is the type of `form.area.choices` and what does calling `insert` on that class do?